# How to randomly pick an index of a given value in a list?

Tags: python, list, random

Assume I have the following 8x8 2D list:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0],
[0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1],
[-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0]]
```

How do I get a random index for the value "1" for example ?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, I assume this is a generic python list and you're not using numpy?

Comment: Is this matrix always rectangular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the list is rectangular (all elements are lists and these lists have the same length and the elements of these lists are numbers), we can boost the filtering process by using `numpy` instead:

```
from numpy import array, where
from random import choice

choice(array(where(a == 1)).T)
```

In case `a` is not an numpy array yet, we can convert it with:

```
choice(array(where(array(a) == 1)).T)
```

This then for instance returns:

```
>>> choice(array(where(a == 1)).T)
array([1, 2])
```

In case we want the result to be a `list` or `tuple`, we can call the constructor, like:

```
>>> tuple(choice(array(where(a == 1)).T))
(1, 6)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a nice one-liner with a nested list comprehension:

```
import random
random.choice([(i, j) for i, row in enumerate(x) for j, val in enumerate(row) if val == 1])
```

where x is your list. You just gather a list of indices `(i, j)` where `val == 1`, then randomly pick one.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
indices = []
for row_idx in range(len(a)):
  for col_idx in range(len(a[row_idx])):
    num = a[row_idx][col_idx]
    if num == 1:
      indices.append((row_idx, col_idx))

import random
rand_idx = random.randrange(0, len(indices))
print indices[rand_idx]
```